# HP DL360 G5 Processor Upgrade

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, xeon, central-processing-unit

I've recently acquired a DL360 G5 with Xeon 5410's in it (quad core, 2.3Ghz).

We've also purchased some Xeon X5482's - which I understand are near the top of that same processor range.  I'd like to upgrade this G5 with the faster processors, but when I swap out the processors, and turn on the machine, it simply sits there in "high fan" power on mode, and never comes out.

Is some sort of BIOS upgrade required?  Can the G5 handle this processor?  I'm having a hard time finding the docs (they are compatible with 5410 and 5420 for sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The highest-clocked CPU I've ever seen installed in that model of server is the Intel X5470 (3.33GHz). The firmware or motherboard may not allow for the CPU that you're trying to use. Check the [firmware release notes for more information](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121486&swItem=MTX-dab5369e3ed64527a2c5b5e815&prodNameId=3288144&swEnvOID=4004&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=5). The X5482 (3.20GHz) is a 1600MHz front side bus CPU. The G5 ProLiants use the Intel 5000P chipset, which only supports (up-to) 1333MHz bus speeds.

From the [ProLiant DL360 G5 quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12476_div/12476_div.HTML).

```
Intel® 5000P chipset supporting up to a 1333MHz Front Side Bus (FSB)
```

Digging a bit further, the chipset on that server, the Intel 5000P, does not support the FSB speed needed for the X5482 CPUs you have. Later versions, like the 5400 Seaburg chipset, do support that particular CPU.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Xeon_chipsets#Dual_processor_Core-based_Xeon_chipsets

Personally, I would try to find a deal on the X5450 (3.0GHz), X5460 (3.16GHz) or X5470 (3.33GHz) CPU kits (HP part# 487511-B21) if you're determined to keep using those systems. However, the advent of the Nehalem and Westmere CPUs in the ProLiant G6 and G7 range represented a massive jump in performance for the applications I deal with. You may realize a more dramatic speed increase by going that direction over the clock-speed improvement from upgrading 2008-era processors.

Comment: Although the X5492 (3.4Ghz) would physically fit and probably run on the HP BIOS it's a 150W TDP part and that server's only designed for 120W TDP parts, so it'd eventually run too hot and you'd see chip failure.

Answer (score 1):

Other HP proliant's I've used only accept HP branded CPUs.  So it doesn't matter if its a similar Xeon, it had to be an official HP one.

The specs of the supported cpus are at
 http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12476_div/12476_div.HTML

You can check for newer firmware:
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodNameId=3288144&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121486&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4024